# Regex match after a string or before end of line

Tags: regex

I would like to grab match after "jsession" or before end of line.
I wrote something that partially works but doesn't work if the match is at the end of the line.

Ex1:

- `/uims/portal/IDV_CAM10_AUTHENTICATION;jsessionid=0000OYmR64-Ta621IoBwHtBKJHu:14ak8djk8?__trats=&__arxasnkucl=b8eb142325f2478896d7ccf53d072646579e99e0db0cec837ee5826bc3f922e8&__dne=`

Ex2:

- `/uims/portal/IDV_CAM10_AUTHENTICATION;jsessionid=0000OYmR64-Ta621IoBwHtBKJHu:14ak8djk8#__trats=&__arxasnkucl=b8eb142325f2478896d7ccf53d072646579e99e0db0cec837ee5826bc3f922e8&__dne=`

Ex3:

- `/uims/portal/IDV_CAM10_AUTHENTICATION;jsessionid=0000OYmR64-Ta621IoBwHtBKJHu:14ak8djk8`

Regex : `(?<=jsessionid=).*(?=\?|#)`
Works for 1&2 but not 3.

See
https://regexr.com/40f35

Comment: How about `(?<=jsessionid=).*?(?=\?|#|$)` ?

Comment: @Marco - Thanks, this works. I would accept this as an answer only because it was closer to my actual original effort but seems I can't make comments as answers on here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
jsessionid=([^#?]+)
```

That will match from `jessionid=` to either `#`, `?`, or end of the string, whichever comes first.  It's using a negative character class, that's what the `[^stuff]` is.  Very handy.  Here is a demo:

https://regex101.com/r/m4WZN4/1

Comment: much simpler than my original effort. Like it :)